# Download file automatically when content locker closes

Tags: javascript

At the moment I'm using this for the users to download the content after they have completed/closed the content locker:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="javascript:open('/<?php echo "$file_name"; ?>.zip')">Download</a>
```

but the content locker has the option to "Execute Javascript" on close.

What JS code should I use in the content locker so that when user closes it, the download to start automatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution is:

```
window.location='/<?php echo "$file_name"; ?>.zip';
```

If you want, you can open new tab/window... Or you can try some library... Like this one - https://github.com/PixelsCommander/Download-File-JS

Comment: thanks for your reply, the code you posted is really simple and should normally work but for some reason, the content locker doesn't accept <?php echo "$file_name"; ?> as part of a JS code [printscreen](http://prntscr.com/6vphlh)  so I think I need something more elaborated - I was thinking to put your code in a .js file and call it from the content locker but I'm not sure how to do that either

Comment: `<?php echo "$file_name"; ?>` part is to generate file name... is you have static js you can replace it with something like `window.location='/file.zip';`